# Angular $q.reject not resolving

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, promise

I have a very simple function in a jasmine test where I am simply returning $q.reject

```
var mockFunction = function() {
                return $q.reject("error");
        };
```

which I call:

```
mockFunction().catch(function(){
// ... blah
});
```

the catch callback function is never being invoked. If I understand correctly $q.resolve should create a promise, rejected immediately and return the rejected promise so I'm not sure why this is not working

Any insights are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you writing tests?  Promise resolution/rejection is tied to the angular digest loop, so frequently in tests you need to add a `$rootScope.$apply()` call.

Comment: you're right, stupid me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$q promise chains aren't executed automatically in specs, it should be

```
mockFunction().catch(function(){
// ... blah
});
$rootScope.$digest();
```

to launch it, the chain will be executed synchronously in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure that it makes any real difference, but FWIW the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#testing) use `$rootScope.$apply()` instead of `$digest`

Comment: It is the matter of semantics if it is $digest or $apply. In production the one may always want to use $apply, preferably with expression argument, it essentially puts safeguards around $digest. $rootScope.$digest() is widely used in specs to just trigger a digest on root scope, there's no danger to use it explicitly there.